# href download xlsx file would be occasionally corrupted

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, xlsx

I'm working on Angular4 with Typescript.

I was able to create a blob using XLSX-populate library.

assume below blob is a valid xlsx object

```
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = "download file.xlsx";
          a.click();
```

I saved the blob variable during execution. 
Then manually ran this block ONLY about 20 times. (the blob was not remade or overwritten)

The result is inconsistent.

The downloaded XLSX file would sometimes be corrupted while other times it was not.

I looked into the async nature of javascript, however since the blob was already created and some tries was able to produce functioning xlsx files. I'm at a complete loss as to what to do next.

Update: 
Still not resolved. But I triggered the click event on the SAME href 4x back to back with no other lines in between and I got 2 working versions and 2 failing versions.

Comment: try deep cloning hope it will work

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Thanks for the input. I tried to do a blob.slice() instead of blob. Didn't work either. Exact same behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may not exactly be an answer. But I've found that by simply waiting a few seconds the xlsx file would be completely fine. Even files that first failed when initially opened will be able to be opened if I retried.

This led me to believe it has something to do with the way chrome detects that the file is ready.

However it ultimately wasn't an issue with the href download.